# generalize lower semi continous function $f:X--->R^{n}$

Tags: functional-analysis

By a lower semicontinuous function $f:X--->R$, where $X$ is complete metric space we mean $x_{n}-->x$ implies $fx_{n} >= fx$. Can we generalize it to define a lower semicontinuos function $f:X--->R^{n}$

Comment: It's a nontrivial task, you should try and search results about semicontinuity for vector-valued functions.

Comment: Note that the TeX code \to gives you $\to$.

Comment: Yes. For vector valued functions in general. Thanks